# how to remove the default behavior for select widget in jquery mobile

Tags: select, jquery-mobile

By default, select tag in jquery mobile is associated with certain behavior. I want to remove this default behavior as I am adding a new behavior of my own. How can I remove this default behavior totally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Preventing auto-initialization of form elements**
>
> If you'd prefer
>   that a particular form control be left untouched by jQuery Mobile,
>   simply give that element the attribute data-role="none". For example:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/forms/docs-forms.html